# Generate a set number of divs with a certain class

Tags: jquery, animation, html, insert

What I'm trying to do is create something that looks like a set of music visualizer bars.  I've got the looks and the animation down-pat, but I need the visualizer to have several dozen bars.  I figured it would be easier---and more semantic---to use jQuery than to manually create the divs.

How do I create a jQuery script that generates a set number of divs with a certain class (the class of the bars) and inserts them inside of another div?

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var nrOfDivs = 12 // for example
  for (i=0;i<nrOfDivs;i++) {
    $('#divToAppendTo').append('<div class="music_visualizer_bar"></div>');
  };

});
```

Just change the nrOfDivs to the amount of divs you need :)